# Python : append mysql results

Tags: python, mysql-python

Here's my script.

```
import _mysql

db=_mysql.connect("localhost","01","","z")

db.query("select id from a limit 2")

result = db.store_result()

while True:
    record = result.fetch_row()
    if not record: break
    print record
```

(execution & the outcome) is :

```
[root@ooo ~]# python a.py
(('1',),)
(('2',),)
[root@ooo ~]#
```

the results are correct but i would like it append all the results and simply print ( based on above output )

```
12
```

Comment: Are you aware of the join function in Python? There is also a group_concat function in MySQL that would allow you to do this directly in the query.

Comment: @John Barça, i was thinking about setting a variable to blank .. & then appending within the loop.  variable = []  and then variable.append(record) ?

Comment: Sundar has given you an answer just like that. I always favour doing things at the db, if possible, but that approach will work.

Comment: Is there a reason for not using `import MySQLdb` and what it provides?

Comment: @glglgl, i was using MySQLdb but there was constant and random caching from mysql results. i did not find info on how to turn that cache-ing off. switched to _mysql and problem went away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    import _mysql

db=_mysql.connect("localhost","sundar","","test")

db.query("select username from auth_user")

result = db.store_result()
r=""
while True:
    record = result.fetch_row()
    if not record: break
    elif record is None:break
    else:r+= record[0][0]
print r
```

Comment: add the print r at the end of line i think ur intendation is wrong

Comment: actually worked fine.  i had indented the print r by mistake.